# removing the middle member or members from list in python

Tags: python

I have this code. Everything is okay but it is not printing the desired values.
I think something is wrong in calling function but I can't figure it out.
this code is removing the middle element if the list length is odd, or the middle two elements if the length is even.
This is the code,

```
One_Ten = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def removeMiddle(data:list)-> list:
    index = 0
    size = len(data)
    index = size // 2


    if (size % 2 == 0 ):
        data = data[:index-1] + data[index+1:]


    if (size % 2 == 1):
        data.pop(index)

    return data

data = list(One_Ten)
removeMiddle(data)
print("After removing the middle element (s):why ", data)
```

so the desired output should look like
[1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10]

Comment: `data = data[:index-1] + data[index+1:]` *does not modify* the list that was passed in. It creates a *new* list; which you then `return`, but you don't do anything with the `return`ed value.

Comment: but when i print  (data) right before the return it prints the correct values

Comment: Like @KarlKnechtel say, you need something like `result = removeMiddle(data)` and `print(result)`. By the way `removeMiddle` and `One_Ten` are not appropriate Python names - you'll do yourself a favour learning Python naming conventions early on

Comment: The `data` inside the function is not the same variable as the `data` outside - they have the same name and initially they point to the same list, but that changes when you reassign it in the function. `data` is just a name for the list and you use that name twice.

Comment: i just did data = removeMiddle(data) and it printed ok. is it ok?

Comment: Do you want to modify One_Ten? the `data` you printed out is a new list after removing elements, try print(One_Ten) and you will see One_Ten have not changed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign `data` it's new value,

```
data = removeMiddle(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Altertnately you can me the function inplace by editing the first conditions

```
if (size % 2 == 0):
    data.pop(index)
    data.pop(index-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
size = len(data)
middle = size // 2

if size % 2 == 0:
    data.pop(middle - 1)
    data.pop(middle - 1)
else:
    if size % 2 == 1:
        data.pop(middle)
```